# How to match specific part of the URI string based on the following characters / words

Tags: java, string, pattern-matching

I am trying to match particular part of the URI only when it is not followed by anything, or when it followed by '?'.

```
.../survey?expand=all  //should match    
.../survey             //should match   
.../survey/..          //should not match
```

I could not find a way to do that in one pattern. I tried `(?=.*survey(?!\\?))` and did not work. I also could not find a way to do it in two separate patterns. For example, I want to match `.../survey` and not `.../survey/...` but this `.*?/survey\\b` did not work for me.

My parser:

```
public class UriParser {

    private static String reqUriPath = null;
    private static String pattern = null;


    public static Boolean isURIMatching(Object routePattern, String pattern){
        reqUriPath = routePattern.toString();
        return checkPattern(reqUriPath, pattern);
    }


    private static Boolean checkPattern(String reqUriPath, String pattern) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(reqUriPath);
        return m.find();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated my regex with better answer

```
\\/survey(?(?=\\?)\\S*|$)
```

**Explanation:**

Here **`(?(?=\\?)\\S*|$)`** is basically an If clause i.e. `(?=\\?) --> if(contains ?)` else |$ so we have following condition :- 
  **1.** `?=<condition>` i.e. `\\? --> ?` i.e. literal ? , so if ? is found in the String then allow \S* any nonwhite space. 
  **2.** `|` is Else condition i.e. else the string must end there, hence no chance of matching / any further.

If you feel confused with the explanation you can check out below link for regex 101 which has a coll explanation about the regex with all the description 
https://regex101.com/r/WCt3WB/2

Comment: yes it works. Can you explain more how you did this logic: after 'sruvey' if '?' or nothing then match, else does not match. In other words, how you made '?' optional

Comment: @Hawk also please accept the answer if you feels so.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to match particular part of the URI only when it is not followed by anything, or when it followed by '?'.

You can do this without Regex;

```
public class UriParser {

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println(isURIMatching("http://test.com/survey?expand=all", "survey"));
        System.out.println(isURIMatching("http://test.com/survey", "survey"));
        System.out.println(isURIMatching("http://test.com/survey/anything", "survey"));
     }

    public static Boolean isURIMatching(Object routePattern, String pattern){
        final String reqUriPath = routePattern.toString();
        final int lastIndex = reqUriPath.lastIndexOf(pattern);
        final String lastPart = reqUriPath.substring(lastIndex+pattern.length()).trim();
        return "".equals(lastPart) || lastPart.startsWith("?");
    }
}
```